# Django CKEditor add YouTube plugin

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I was trying to find answer for my question, but still couldn't figure it out.

I have my model with field:

```
description = RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name='Description', config_name='special')
```

In `settings.py` I have:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        "removePlugins": "stylesheetparser",
        'toolbar_Custom': [
             ['Bold', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Image'],
         ],
         },
    'special':
        {
            'toolbar': 'Special',
            'enterMode': 2,
            'height': 500,
            'width': 1100,
            "removePlugins": "stylesheetparser",
            'extraAllowedContent': 'iframe[*]',
            'toolbar_Special':
            [
            ......
        {
            'name': 'youtube',
            'items': ['Youtube',]
        },
            ],

         }
}
```

And it works, but youtube icon doesn't display on my toolbar. Searching for solution I read I have to put [youtube-plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/youtube) in ckeditor config. So in my folder project (where all apps are created) I created `ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/`. Like on attached image. [image]. Unfortunately the option to add youtube video still don't display on toolbar. Is there something I'm doing wrong or need to do something else?